# Jquery vertical multilevel menu parent li catches mouseclicks of inner ul?

Tags: jquery, css, menu

I'm trying to make a vertical multilevel menu for small screens.

I start with adding a css-class called 'hidden to all `ul` items within a `li`. I do this with jquery. This class hass the properties `visibility:hidden`, `opacity:0` and `height:0`

If one clicks on a `li` with a `ul` inside, the 'hidden'-class is removed, and a 'active'-class is added (to that `ul`). I do this with jquery. This class had the properties `visibility:visible`, `opacity:1` and `height:auto`.

```js
$(".menu > li > ul").addClass("hidden");
 $(".menu > li > ul > li > ul").addClass("hidden");
 
 $(".menu > li").has("ul").click(function(){
        if ( $(this).children("ul").hasClass( "hidden" ) ) {
            $(this).children("ul").removeClass("hidden");
            $(this).children("ul").addClass("active");
        } else {
            $(this).children("ul").removeClass("active");
            $(this).children("ul").addClass("hidden");
        }
    });

    $(".menu > li > ul > li").has("ul").click(function(){
        if ( $(this).children("ul").hasClass( "hidden" ) ) {
            $(this).children("ul").removeClass("hidden");
            $(this).children("ul").addClass("active");
        } else {
            $(this).children("ul").removeClass("active");
            $(this).children("ul").addClass("hidden");
        }
    });
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About 1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About 1.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Hello</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Hello 1.1</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Hello 1.2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Hello 1.2.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hello 1.2.2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hello 1.2.3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Hello 1.3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

All the `ul` and `li` items have position:static in css. The `a` items have position:block.

**PROBLEM**

If I click on the `li` About, the `ul` within About gets shown. However, if I click on `li` About 1.1, the forementioned `ul` gets hidden again (it gets assigned the css-class 'hidden').

I *think* the `li` About somehow 'catches' the mouseclick (because it's the encompassing parent), making jquery remove the 'active'-class and applying the 'hidden'-class.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply click event to `a` not directly to entire `li`

Please check below code:

```js
$(".menu > li > ul").addClass("hidden");
$(".menu > li > ul > li > ul").addClass("hidden");

$(".menu > li a").click(function(){
 if ( $(this).parent().children("ul").hasClass( "hidden" ) ) {
  $(this).parent().children("ul").removeClass("hidden");
  $(this).parent().children("ul").addClass("active");
 } else {
  $(this).parent().children("ul").removeClass("active");
  $(this).parent().children("ul").addClass("hidden");
 }
});
```

```css
.hidden{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About 1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About 1.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Hello</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Hello 1.1</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Hello 1.2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Hello 1.2.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hello 1.2.2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hello 1.2.3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Hello 1.3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

More detail:

If you applies `click` event on `li` it it will make visible sub `ul li` for first time, but when you click on "About 1.1" you are clicking on its parent first.

Please see below image to get idea that, when the menu is open entire `li` will consider that click event

[image]

Comment: You sir, are a genius. I already suspected that the parent-li was responding to a click on it's inner elements. The following is working for the sub-menu AND sub-sub-menu. I believe you forgot 1 parent()? 

`$(".menu > li a").click(function(){ if ( $(this).parent().children("ul").hasClass( "hidden" ) ) { $(this).parent().children("ul").removeClass("hidden"); $(this).parent().children("ul").addClass("active"); } else { $(this).parent().children("ul").removeClass("active"); $(this).parent().children("ul").addClass("hidden"); } });`